# How can I determine the area currently visible in a scrollview and determine the center?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a map app where the user can place waypoints manually. I would like for them to press the waypoint button and have a waypoint placed in the center of their currently visible view on the content view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to account for how zoomed it is, then I can convert the content offset to the size of the full image and add some.
        /// this is the full size of the map image
        CGSize fullSize = CGPointMake(13900, 8400);

```
    /// determines how the current content size compares to the full size
    float zoomFactor = size.width/self.contentSize.width; 

    /// apply the zoom factor to the content offset , this basically upscales 
    /// the content offset to apply to the dimensions of the full size map

    float newContentOffsetX = self.contentOffset.x*zoomFactor + (self.bounds.size.width/2) *zoomFactor-300;
    float newContentOffsetY = self.contentOffset.y*zoomFactor + (self.bounds.size.height/2) * zoomFactor-300;

    /// not sure why i needed to subtract the 300, but the formula wasn't putting 
    /// the point in the exact center, subtracting 300 put it there in all situations though 

    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(newContentOffsetX,newContentOffsetY );
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you'd have to calculate it yourself. `contentSize` returns size of the scrolled content, `contentOffset` gives you the origin of the scroll view inside the content. Then with `scrollView.bounds.size` you can find the center of the view.

Haven't tested this, but maybe you could convert `scrollView.center` to your scrolled map like this:

```
CGPoint viewportCenterInMapCoords = 
        [scrollView.superview convertPoint:scrollView.center
                                    toView:mapViewInsideScrollView];
```

Comment: Thanks - the code you provided did not quite work, although your answer did lead me to coming up with the answer. The problem was accounting for the zoom factor.